# Memory errors, don't know why that is happening

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have some memory errors that I can't understand what is and why it's happening;
Here are typedefs from source file gentree.c:

```
typedef struct _ELEMENT* PELEMENT; /* definition that PELEMENT is a pointer to  _ELEMENT*/
typedef struct _ELEMENT
{
  pNode obj; /*the id or content of the node*/
  PELEMENT* children; /* array of pointers*/
  PELEMENT parent; /*pointer*/
  int childrenCount; /* number of pointers at "children" array*/
} ELEMENT;

/* definition of the tree structure */
typedef struct _tree{
  PELEMENT head;
  int k;    /* the max number of children for each node*/
  GetKeyFunction getKeyFunc;
  CloneFunction cloneFunc;
  PrintFunction printFunc;
  DelFunction delFunc;

} Tree;
```

Here's the problematic piece of code (from source file gentree.c):
I'm calling this function from another one, also found in gentree.c, but the error happenes here:

```
Result DelAux(PELEMENT head, int key,PTree pStruct )
{
    PELEMENT saveParent;
int i=0, j=0;
    Result deleted=FAILURE; /*a variable to know if the leaf is successfully deleted*/
if(pStruct->getKeyFunc(head->obj)==key) /*if the current node is the wanted node*/
    {

    pStruct->delFunc(head->obj); /*first of all dlete the pointer to the node*/
    if(head->parent!=NULL) /*if it's not the root*/
    {
      (head->parent->childrenCount)--; /*decrease the number of the father's     children by one */
      if((head->parent->childrenCount)==0) /*if that was the last child of its father*/
      {
      saveParent=head->parent;
      free(head); /*free the pointer to the current node's element in tree*/
      head=NULL; /*and make it points to null*/
      free(saveParent->children); /*then free the pointer to childrens' array*/
      saveParent->children=NULL;  /*make the pointer to childrens' array points to null*/
      }
   }   
   else
   {
       free(head); /*free the pointer to the current node's element in tree*/
       head=NULL; /*and make it points to null*/
   }
        return SUCCESS;
   } 

   if (head->children==NULL)
   {
    return FAILURE;
   }
   else /*if the current node is not the wanted node*/
   {
       while(i<pStruct->k && j<head->childrenCount) /*then look for the wanted node it in the children of current node*/
       {
       if(head->children[i]!=NULL) /*if there is some child in this cell*/
       {
            j++;
                deleted=DelAux(head->children[i], key, pStruct);
                if(deleted==SUCCESS) /*if succeeded to delete*/
        {
                   return SUCCESS;
        }
           }
       i++;
       }

  }
  return FAILURE ; /*if didn't succeed */
}
/***********************************************************************/
```

And here's the functions from the source file -partition.c:

```
 typedef struct _OBJ* POBJ; 
 typedef struct _OBJ
 {
    double xi;
    double xf;
    double yi;
    double yf;
    int key;
 }
 PART;
/************************************************/
 int GetKey(pNode e)
{
POBJ p=NULL;
p=(POBJ)e;
return p->key; /*return the key of the node*/
}
/************************************************/
void Del(pNode e)
{
    POBJ p=NULL;
p= (POBJ)e; /*p pointe to the node we want to delete*/
free(p);    /*free the memory the node catches*/
p=NULL;    /*make it point to null*/
}
/************************************************/
```

And here's the valgrind output:

```
==24885== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==24885== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==24885== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==24885== Command: ./partition
==24885== Parent PID: 24884
==24885== 
--24885-- 
--24885-- Valgrind options:
--24885--    -v
--24885--    --log-file=log1
--24885--    --leak-check=full
--24885--    --tool=memcheck
--24885-- Contents of /proc/version:
--24885--   Linux version 2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-     022.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC) ) #1 SMP    Mon Jun 17 15:54:20 EDT 2013
--24885-- Arch and hwcaps: AMD64, amd64-sse3-cx16-avx
--24885-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 4096
--24885-- Valgrind library directory: /usr/lib64/valgrind
--24885-- Reading syms from /u1/004/syoavb/hm3/300028420/partition
--24885-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
--24885--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
--24885-- Reading syms from /lib64/ld-2.12.so
--24885-- Scheduler: using generic scheduler lock implementation.
--24885-- Reading suppressions file: /usr/lib64/valgrind/default.supp
==24885== embedded gdbserver: reading from /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-24885-by-syoavb-   on-t2.technion.ac.il
==24885== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-24885-by-syoavb-on-t2.technion.ac.il
==24885== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-24885-by-  syoavb-on-t2.technion.ac.il
==24885== 
==24885== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
==24885== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
==24885== or are doing some strange experiment):
==24885==   /usr/lib64/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=24885 ...command...
==24885== 
==24885== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==24885==   /path/to/gdb ./partition
==24885== and then give GDB the following command
==24885==   target remote | /usr/lib64/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=24885
==24885== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==24885== 
--24885-- REDIR: 0x3fc8217520 (strlen) redirected to 0x38049551   (vgPlain_amd64_linux_REDIR_FOR_strlen)
--24885-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
--24885-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
--24885-- REDIR: 0x3fc8217390 (index) redirected to 0x4a07bf0 (index)
--24885-- REDIR: 0x3fc8217410 (strcmp) redirected to 0x4a08530 (strcmp)
--24885-- Reading syms from /lib64/libc-2.12.so
--24885-- REDIR: 0x3fc8684e80 (strcasecmp) redirected to 0x480155c   (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--24885-- REDIR: 0x3fc8687140 (strncasecmp) redirected to 0x480155c (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--24885-- REDIR: 0x3fc8682df0 (__GI_strrchr) redirected to 0x4a07a70 (__GI_strrchr)
--24885-- REDIR: 0x3fc867a8a0 (malloc) redirected to 0x4a0696c (malloc)
--24885-- REDIR: 0x3fc867a4e0 (calloc) redirected to 0x4a056d7 (calloc)
--24885-- REDIR: 0x3fc867b6d0 (free) redirected to 0x4a06369 (free)
--24885-- REDIR: 0x3fc8683500 (memchr) redirected to 0x4a085d0 (memchr)
--24885-- REDIR: 0x3fc8689820 (memcpy) redirected to 0x4a08b20 (memcpy)
--24885-- REDIR: 0x3fc8681310 (__GI_strlen) redirected to 0x4a07f70 (__GI_strlen)
--24885-- REDIR: 0x3fc868aca0 (strchrnul) redirected to 0x4a09f10 (strchrnul)
--24885-- REDIR: 0x3fc86846b0 (mempcpy) redirected to 0x4a09f80 (mempcpy)
==24885== Invalid read of size 4
==24885==    at 0x401FD0: GetKey (partition.c:342)
==24885==    by 0x40110F: DelAux (gentree.c:447)
==24885==    by 0x401213: DelAux (gentree.c:488)
==24885==    by 0x4010D1: TreeDelLeaf (gentree.c:433)
==24885==    by 0x4008C8: DestroyAux (gentree.c:115)
==24885==    by 0x400915: DestroyAux (gentree.c:124)
==24885==    by 0x400865: TreeDestroy (gentree.c:98)
==24885==    by 0x4019CF: DeletePartition (partition.c:177)
==24885==    by 0x402142: main (main.c:40)
==24885==  Address 0x4c23570 is 32 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd
==24885==    at 0x4A063F0: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:446)
==24885==    by 0x401FA9: Del (partition.c:334)
==24885==    by 0x40112C: DelAux (gentree.c:455)
==24885==    by 0x401213: DelAux (gentree.c:488)
==24885==    by 0x4010D1: TreeDelLeaf (gentree.c:433)
==24885==    by 0x4008C8: DestroyAux (gentree.c:115)
==24885==    by 0x400915: DestroyAux (gentree.c:124)
==24885==    by 0x400865: TreeDestroy (gentree.c:98)
==24885==    by 0x4019CF: DeletePartition (partition.c:177)
==24885==    by 0x402142: main (main.c:40)
==24885== 
==24885== 
==24885== HEAP SUMMARY:
==24885==     in use at exit: 376 bytes in 11 blocks
==24885==   total heap usage: 98 allocs, 87 frees, 3,776 bytes allocated
==24885== 
==24885== Searching for pointers to 11 not-freed blocks
==24885== Checked 129,912 bytes
==24885== 
==24885== 376 (64 direct, 312 indirect) bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 3
==24885==    at 0x4A0577B: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:593)
==24885==    by 0x400C95: TreeAddLeaf (gentree.c:278)
==24885==    by 0x401942: RefineCell (partition.c:151)
==24885==    by 0x4020BB: main (main.c:28)
==24885== 
==24885== LEAK SUMMARY:
==24885==    definitely lost: 64 bytes in 2 blocks
==24885==    indirectly lost: 312 bytes in 9 blocks
==24885==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24885==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24885==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24885== 
==24885== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
==24885== 
==24885== 1 errors in context 1 of 2:
==24885== Invalid read of size 4
==24885==    at 0x401FD0: GetKey (partition.c:342)
==24885==    by 0x40110F: DelAux (gentree.c:447)
==24885==    by 0x401213: DelAux (gentree.c:488)
==24885==    by 0x4010D1: TreeDelLeaf (gentree.c:433)
==24885==    by 0x4008C8: DestroyAux (gentree.c:115)
==24885==    by 0x400915: DestroyAux (gentree.c:124)
==24885==    by 0x400865: TreeDestroy (gentree.c:98)
==24885==    by 0x4019CF: DeletePartition (partition.c:177)
==24885==    by 0x402142: main (main.c:40)
==24885==  Address 0x4c23570 is 32 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd
==24885==    at 0x4A063F0: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:446)
==24885==    by 0x401FA9: Del (partition.c:334)
==24885==    by 0x40112C: DelAux (gentree.c:455)
==24885==    by 0x401213: DelAux (gentree.c:488)
==24885==    by 0x4010D1: TreeDelLeaf (gentree.c:433)
==24885==    by 0x4008C8: DestroyAux (gentree.c:115)
==24885==    by 0x400915: DestroyAux (gentree.c:124)
==24885==    by 0x400865: TreeDestroy (gentree.c:98)
==24885==    by 0x4019CF: DeletePartition (partition.c:177)
==24885==    by 0x402142: main (main.c:40)
==24885== 
--24885-- 
--24885-- used_suppression:      4 U1004-ARM-_dl_relocate_object
--24885-- used_suppression:      2 glibc-2.5.x-on-SUSE-10.2-(PPC)-2a
==24885== 
==24885== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

What is exactly happening here?!

Comment: The message seems reasonably self-explanatory; you're trying to read from memory that you've already freed. As to why that's happening, well you'll need to use a debugger to trace your pointers.

Comment: Note that your code in `GetKey()` that reads: `POBJ p=NULL;
p=(POBJ)e;` could be simpler: `POBJ p = (POBJ)e;` (there is no point in initializing to NULL and then immediately assigning). Similarly, in  `Del` you don't need to assign NULL to the local variable that is about to go out of scope.  In `DelAux()`, when you assign to `head`, you are only affecting the local variable (function parameter), not the pointer in the calling function.  This means that your calling function may not realize that the data it is accessing has already been freed.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler can you explain please what do you mean by "assign to head", to which line are you relating ? And the problem as I understood is that head->obj has been freed somewhere and therefore when we call Getkey there's a memory error, tell me if I'm wrong please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented:

> Note that your code in `GetKey()` that reads:
>
> ```
> POBJ p=NULL;
> p=(POBJ)e;
> ```
>
> could be simpler:
>
> ```
> POBJ p = (POBJ)e;
> ```
>
> (there is no point in initializing to NULL and then immediately
>   assigning). Similarly, in `Del` you don't need to assign NULL to the
>   local variable that is about to go out of scope.

These are trite observations; accurate, but not a source of the immediate problem.

I note in passing we do not have the definition of the `pNode` type anywhere (which is the type of `e` passed to `GetKey()`).  There are numerous other types missing too; this is not, therefore, an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)). This means mainly that we can't test the code (without doing undue work), but it doesn't prevent us from making some observations about the code.

I also commented:

> In `DelAux()`, when you
>   assign to `head`, you are only affecting the local variable (function
>   parameter), not the pointer in the calling function. This means that
>   your calling function may not realize that the data it is accessing
>   has already been freed.

And [user2750466](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2750466/user2750466) asked:

> Can you explain please what do you mean by "assign to head", to which line are you relating? And the problem as I understood is that `head->obj` has been freed somewhere and therefore when we call `Getkey()` there's a memory error; tell me if I'm wrong please.

This is going to take too much space to be sensible as commentary, hence it becomes an answer.  Whether it solves the whole problem is a separate discussion.

The code I referred to is in `DelAux()`; a relevant de-commented extract is:

```
Result DelAux(PELEMENT head, int key, PTree pStruct)
{
    PELEMENT saveParent;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    Result deleted = FAILURE;
    if (pStruct->getKeyFunc(head->obj) == key)
    {
        pStruct->delFunc(head->obj);
        if (head->parent != NULL)
        {
            (head->parent->childrenCount)--;
            if ((head->parent->childrenCount) == 0)
            {
                saveParent = head->parent;
                free(head);
                head = NULL;  // This is (1)
                free(saveParent->children);
                saveParent->children = NULL;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            free(head);
            head = NULL;  // This is (2)
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    ...
```

The `head` variable is passed to this function as a value; it is a pointer, but it is a local variable to the `DelAux()` function.  I've identified two locations in the code where you assign `NULL` to `head`, and this is pointless because you affect only the local variable `head`, not the pointer in the calling function (which is, on occasion, `DelAux()`, and on other occasions `TreeDelLeaf()` — according to the traces from `valgrind`.

It is possible (plausible) that you need to pass in `ELEMENT **head` (or `PELEMENT *head` — they're the same thing, but I prefer not to disguise the pointers, so I personally would not create or use the `PELEMENT` typedef), so you could then write:

```
*head = NULL;
```

and it would affect the variable in the calling code.  There'd be analogous changes elsewhere in the function, of course — every reference to `head` would need to be reviewed and most would need to be replaced by `*head`, or you'd create a local `ELEMENT *l_head = *head;` which you'd use in place of `head` except when you wanted to modify the value in the calling function.

Now, it is possible that the line `pStruct->delFunc(head->obj);` is a (the) recursive call to `DelAux()` — we can't tell because we don't have enough code (SSCCE again). If that is a call to `DelAux()`, then under the revised function definition, that would become:

```
pStruct->delFunc(&head->obj);
```

This passes the address of the pointer to the function, so the function can modify the pointer — specifically set it to NULL — and the calling function will be aware.  As currently written, the called function sets its copy of `head->obj` to NULL without affecting `head->obj` itself.

This is the gist of my comment explained.  It is a common problem for people learning C and building tree structures, etc.  There are quite a lot of similar questions here on SO.

Given that I don't have working code (and I don't want to see a copy of all your code; I would like the … let's say 100-line SSCCE created from your code, but it needs to be that small, or smaller, and all in a single file because it is that small), I'm not really willing to pontificate further.

Comment: Since your answer already contains a lot, you could add that the key element of the pNode that he's trying to access may be unallocated, that's why there's an invalid read of size 4. Also, he's trying to free a pointer which has already been free'd in `Del()`.

Comment: @FreeSalad: While that could be the problem, it is not clear that it is the problem.  The `valgrind` report points to using a pointer that has already been freed. Further, it is 32 bytes into an allocation of 40 bytes, so I would guess that it is the `parent` member of `struct _ELEMENT` on a 32-bit compilation (and that `sizeof(pNode)` is therefore 28. (I should also observe that the name `_ELEMENT` is reserved for the implementation and should not be used by this user code.) However, that's more of a guess than a definitive answer; I've not spent the time chasing where the data is used.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler, I think you are right, head is freed but the assignment of NULL for it is not done since it's moved to the function by value and not by reference; and therefore when the function reaches the line: if(head->children[i]!=NULL), it passes the "if condition" because there is no NULL there and on the next recursive call when it gets to GetKey it send head->obj which we freed in a previous call.